# How to switch between databases using GORM in golang?

Tags: mysql, database, go, go-gorm

I'm new to GORM in golang. I'm stuck at a point. Generally we select the database like this:
*DBGorm, err = gorm.Open("mysql", user:password@tcp(host:port)/db_name)*
But my problem is I'll get the 'db_name' in the request, which means I don't know which db_name might come and I'll have to query according to that db_name.
So now, I'll create the database pointer in the init function like this:
*DBGorm, err = gorm.Open("mysql", user:password@tcp(host:port)/)* which is without the db_name.

Now how will I switch to db_name coming to me in request. Because when I try to do *DBGorm.Create(&con)*, it shows **No database selected**.

If I use 'database/sql', then I can make raw queries like this: "SELECT * FROM db_name.table_name", this can solve my problem. But how to do this in gorm?

Comment: A way will be using two different connection for two database of mysql. Write a function take dbname as parameter and return connection

Comment: Ok, so instead of using it in init function, whenever i get a request I'll create a new db_name connection and use it for queries. Is that correct? But what if I have 1000+ db_names, then I'll have 1000+ pointers, are we sure that this won't create any problems related to connections limit reach of that database instance? Because I wont know how any connections of db_names have been opened and on top of that there is no limit to number of db_names that i might have to query.

Comment: Actually I think that if you have 2/3 database then create a connection for each in init and then use when which one needed. And you are right for like `1000+ db_names` it's makes problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify `db_name` and `table_name` using `.Table()` when doing query or other operation on table.

```
DBGorm.Table("db_name.table_name").Create(&con)
```

Comment: @AnkitRohilla Welcome! Try to read here in your spare time https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I saw a related article on Github. https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/173#issuecomment-427721651

All you need to do is

1. start a transaction,
2. set you database
3. run your desired query.
4. and switch back to your desired DB
5. commit once you are done.

below is an example

```
tx := db.Begin() // start transaction
tx.Exec("use " + userDB) // switch to tenant db
tx.Exec("insert into ....") // do some work
tx.Exec("use `no-op-db`") // switch away from tenant db (there is no unuse, so I just use a dummy)
tx.Commit() // end transaction
```